# VSCode terminal - echo $SHELL shows bash, but I've set the shell to zsh

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm one MacOS Catalina with VS Code v1.44.

I've switched my macOS terminal to use Zsh. Using Terminal.app and iTerm.app, when I try the following:

```
echo $0
echo $SHELL
```

...I see the path to Zsh (/bin/zsh)

But when I'm in VS Code and open a terminal...
`echo $0` shows /bin/zsh and `echo $shell` shows /bin/bash.

In my VS Code settings, I've selected Zsh as the terminal shell for macOS.

Can anyone explain (or point me to resources) help understand what's going on here?

Comment: Hi, you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the answer was when you asked this question, but since VS Code 1.56 (April 2021), the way of configuring terminal profiles in VS Code changed. See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_profile-improvements. So I'll answer taking those changes into account.

I'd try putting the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"
```

The default value of that setting is `null`.

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles, which states:

> The default terminal profile shell defaults to $SHELL on Linux and macOS and PowerShell on Windows. VS Code will automatically detect most standard shells that can then be configured as the default.

I'm not sure if that feature came after the version that was the latest when you posted this question originally. If it did come after, it might explain why you were observing the behaviour you saw.